# Django Ordering by property field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-filters

I'm using 'OrderingFilter' to allow ordering.
According to Django documentation, when not specifying 'ordering_fields' you can order by any field that mentioned in the view serializer. I have a field which is basically a @property field in the serializer. But when trying to order by that field, I get the following error:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'spec_identifier' into field. Choices are:....
```

This is part of the model view:

```
class ItemViewSet(BaseViewMixin, MyModelView):
    permission_classes = [MyItemViewPermissions]
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
    filter_backends = (ItemFilter, OrderingFilter,)
```

and this is the property definition I want to order by:

```
@property
def spec_identifier(self):
    return self.spec.identifier if self.spec else None
```

Is it possible to order by it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after research and trial and error, that was the solution:

```
ordering_fields = tuple(serializer_class.Meta.fields + ['spec__identifier'])
```

Comment: Very nice thanks, so much, works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

you can order and get in values property,
but you can order by related field, for example

```
Item.objects.all().order_by('spec__identifier')
```

Comment: I want to allow to do it from client with query param - '?ordering=spec_identifier' using the OrderingfFilter, same as other fields

Comment: did you try `?ordering=spec__identifier` double underscore in query string?

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code.

```
class ItemViewSet(BaseViewMixin, MyModelView):
    permission_classes = [MyItemViewPermissions]
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
    filter_backends = (ItemFilter, OrderingFilter,) 
    ordering_fields = ('spec__identifier',)
```